# Is Service binding approach using spring cloud connectors relevant when credentials are stored in Vault?

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-connectors

I have been using the Spring cloud Service connectors for Pivotal cloud foundry for a long time which gets the connection details from the VCAP_SERVICES env variable. Now we have a requirement to read  these credentials from  Vault . I am just curious , Can I still continue to use the Service binding approach with spring cloud connector ? I would assume we don't want to expose these credentials from vault to an VCAP_SERVICES variable which defeat the purpose of the vault. Has  there been any enhancements in Spring cloud connectors to read the credentials  directly from Vault rather than depending the VCAP_SERVICES env variable  or should I resort back to the Spring boot's default Application Properties based approach instead of the service binding approach using cloud connectors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring Cloud Connectors project is now in [maintenance mode](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors#spring-cloud-connectors-), in favor of the newer [Java CFEnv project](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv). However, Java CFEnv is also very specific to Cloud Foundry's `VCAP_SERVICES` model of exposing service bindings and won't help you if the service connection info is in Vault.

I would suggest that you fall back to the Spring Boot properties-based approach using [Spring Cloud Vault](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-vault/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/) or [Spring Cloud Config Server's Vault integration](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#vault-backend) to automate fetching the properties from Vault and making them available as Spring Boot properties.